# In terms of performance, what is the best-practices way to load images into a JS gallery?

Tags: jquery, performance, image-gallery, preload

I'm building a gallery from scratch that is rendered completely with Javascript/JQuery.

The gallery consists of ~70 photos. The gallery UI will just be previous and next buttons (no thumbnails).

In terms of performance (reduced load times), what is the best-practices way to load the images?

Here are the different techniques I'm considering:

1. On page load, just load the first image, and preload the rest.
2. When the user clicks the "next" button to request an image, use JS to create and append the image tag.

Comment: When you say "performance" you're being too general.  You should ask against some metric.  What do you consider performance?

Comment: In terms of performance, I mean I want to reduce the time between when the user opens the page and is able to view & interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I'd probably load the current image, and 1 or 2 previous/next images. Then each time the next/previous buttons are clicked, load another image a couple placed ahead.

This way you get a good user experience, and also reduce potential download.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider loading the image being viewed and then also pre-loading the adjacent image(s) giving you a best-of-both worlds scenario.  However, some people might argue that this is "over-engineering."  Other people will also probably argue that you should start with some pre-written library.  If you have not looked into that already, that could certainly save you some time.  I apologize if this is obvious to you.

The reason I say this is that its certainly faster if the information is already there instead of having to use ajax to request it.  However, pre-loading 70 photos could cause performance issues in other ways, depending on the browser being used and the strength of the clients system.  Sometimes a process that heavily utilizes resources can cause browsers to lag in ways that seem unrelated, such as the scroll button freezing up.  This is especially true if its someone's $200 netbook with 1gb ram and loaded with bloatware.

I assume you mean to pre-load the images asynchronously.

**Edit:::**

Based on your comment above, it looks like you just want the initial page load to be faster.  In this case, it would probably be best to load as little as possible on page load.  And then use jQuery to append images as the users requests them.  Overall, this approach would probably work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

The second option would be better, where you load additional images *on demand*. Why waste your and your user's bandwidth downloading all images when only the first few may be viewed?

Answer (score 1):

> In terms of performance, I mean I want to reduce the time between when the user opens the page and is able to view & interact with it

Upon this metric, we can say the best solution to your problem is to load the first image they will see (so kinda of #1).  Once this image is done loading, you can enable interaction.  At the same time you will want to start preloading the next few images (and previous if there are) so that they will not wait after interacting with your page.  You can set a buffer number depending on **how large the images are** and **how long you expect them to stay at each image**.  Of course these two ideas offset each other so it's up to you to play around with the value.

Preloading ~70 images can be fine depending on how you're using it.  If you are having to shift every single image upon interaction, then it's not a good idea to preload.  Also, if your images are large, it's not a good idea to preload because you don't want to hog their memory.  Your best bet is just to preload the previous/next few images.